# React - Passing Props across the component tree

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I am relatively new to React and I was wondering if you could pass components across the component tree without having to create the state variable in the parent component.

Things I understand:

1. You could pass props down from parent to child.
2. You cannot pass props up from child to parent.
3. I also understand that you could use context API's to avoid prop drilling. However, the Context.Provider has to be above the Context.Consumer. So that would mean I would have to create the state variables in the parent class. If I want to share the same state between two child components.

There have been times in my React application where I was forced to create a state variable in the parent to share it across two child components. Is there any way I could use the context API or some other method to create the state variable in one of the child components and share that state with another child component.

Comment: You could use Redux to share state across components or to communicate within siblings component you could also use rxjs BehaviourSubject

Comment: Not in an easy way.
Technically its all Javascript so you can manipulate how you like. It can become super complicated and buggy.
But it is best to follow best practices (lifting state up)